# Visual Studio file corrupted after power outage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I had a generic handler C# file, with an "ashx" extension, open in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, when I experienced a sudden power outage.  Now, after restarting my computer and reopening the file, all I see is a bunch of hex values, instead of C# code.

[image: C# file corrupted]

I would ***really*** appreciate some help in recovering the contents of the file.  It's the most important one in the project.

Comment: The bottom of the window indicates you are using TFS. Can you just get it from TFS? Were you using source control at all?

Comment: @vcsjones, unfortunately, I'm away from my office (on urgent family matters) and I have not been able to VPN in since January 23.  I stand to lose about eight days of work.

Comment: sometimes VS2k10 makes a backup of files in case of just such an issue.  usually, though, when you restart it asks you if you want to recover it.  what happens if you open the file in notepad?

Comment: @Muad'Dib I get a "blank" file.  I used quotation marks because the file isn't actually blank.  It has white spaces, and I can move my cursor around (to a certain extent).  But it appears blank.

Comment: Try navigating to the directory where the file(s) are and set that folder to view hidden files. Maybe there is a temp file there.

Comment: @M3NTA7, my Windows Explorer is configured to show hidden files by default.  Unfortunately, there are none in that folder.

Comment: If you have any recent build and you have access to assemblies of that build, maybe you could just use a reflector and extract your code from there

Comment: @sos00, I'll keep that as a project to try sometime later, but right now, since I am getting anxious, I've just decided to try and reproduce the approximately 3,000 lines of code.

Comment: @Shredderroy, Suit yourself but it's just as hard as downloading a reflector tool like Lutz Reflector and doing a copy/paste

Comment: @sos00 As easy as that?  Well, I'm definitely going to try then.  (I guess I am so overcome with anxiety that I am having a hard time thinking straight.)

Comment: @experiancing the same problem due to an unexpected restart, have you found any solution to get the code back?!

Comment: @user1570048 Unfortunately, not.  I had to reproduce all of that code.

Comment: @user1570048 Reflector worked fine for me ;)

Comment: Solution 4 worked for me: http://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/ (=